# How to find acceleration in this rectilinear movement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, jerk

$$x = A + Bt + Ct^2 + Dt^3 $$

where $$C = 0.14~\rm m/s^{2} $$
and $$D = 0.01~\rm m/s^{3} $$

After how much time after the start of movement does the acceleration become 1 m/s^2 and what is the medium acceleration during this time interval?

I am not asking you to solve this, I need to know where shall I start from?

Is this formula enough?

$$x = x_0 + v_0t + a  (t^2) / 2$$

or should I start from $$a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

I am really confused, thanks!

Comment: Hint: the acceleration is the second time derivative of the position.

Comment: You don't need the first formula, the reformulation of the second should suffice.

Comment: Your equation that starts $x=x_0 + \ldots$ is valid only when the acceleration is constant, which is not the case here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to tell that $x = x_0 + v_0t + a  \frac{t^2}{2}$ won't do because you will be missing the $t^3$ term.

Start with $$a = \frac{{\rm d}^2x}{{\rm d}t^2}  $$ and plug and chug the time values.

Comment: so because v = dx / dt and a = dv / dt, it results that a = d2x/ dt2? You really saved me here!    Is the average acceleration supposed to be calculated like some integral from time 1 to time 2?  Thank you again!